# Unable to run python(Selenium) code on UI while embedded with angular on IIS server

Tags: python, angular, iis, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium 2 WebDriver. This project is like report automation which automate Some ERP reports. I embedded Python codes batch file with Angular code.

It works fine when I run code on localhost.

But, when I try to run it directly from IIS,

With local system identity then it runs in background.
We unable to see the process, but we received required output.

So what could be the actual problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. please post more details information about your requirement.